# AngularJS ui route hash prefix

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS ui route for routing I want to remove # (hash from URL). I am using this code and also using (base href="/") in my index.html file. It's working fine but when I refresh the page like (`http://0.0.0.0:3000/athletepersonalinfo`) it's giving me an error.

```
.config(function($stateProvider,$locationProvider) {
   $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false })
   $stateProvider
   .state('/', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl:HTML.HOME,
    controller: 'homeController as home'
    })
   .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'homeController as home',
    templateUrl: HTML.HOME
    })

    .state('athletepersonalinfo', {
    url: '/athletepersonalinfo',
    controller: 'athleteProfileInfo',
    templateUrl: HTML.ATHLETE_PERSONAL_INFO,
    authenticate: true
  })
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @FrankerZ...my landing page state is home when a user login it redirect to http://0.0.0.0:3000/athletepersonalinfo .its also working fine but when i refresh this page its giving error like

    Loopback
    404 Error: Cannot GET /athletepersonalinfo
   at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/home/ali/Desktop/EmpyresServices/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:20:17)

Comment: To remove the hash in the url your should also handle the routes on server side

Answer (score 1):

When you hit refresh the server actually tries to find if the given route has been defined `/athletepersonalinfo`. To actually remove the # from the url you will have to include a `get(/*)` route which would always return your `index.html` page. This route should be after all other routes. Now what this means is your `index.html` will be served whenever no routes is defined than in your client side angular will handle which view to load. Few points to note when making such chages

- Since any unresolved get could return your index.html make sure your routes are meaningful like all your assets start with /assets/ path, all your api calls start with /api/ .
- The benefit in doing so is if you get a 404 on some assets or an api call you would still get your `index.html` which is wrong. But with this approach all you need to do is set a route something like this

  ```
  app.get('/:url(api|assets)/*',function(req,res){
      res.status(400).send("Not Found")
  });

  app.get('/*',function(req,res){
      res.sendFile('index.html');
  });
  ```
- Make sure the * route is defined after all other  routes else you will keep getting index.html for every request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sry but i am not getting your point 

My server.js file 


    app.start = function() {
       // start the web server
      return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};